# A MySql column of type DATE is displayed as one day Earlier in javafx tableview

Tags: java, instant

```
String sql= "SELECT *FROM result WHERE pId=46 AND date='2013-01-01'";
```

The above query returns a result. However, the date is displayed as `2012-12-31` in java code and tableview. It returns all the information which is relevant to the correct date (`2013-01-01`) but the GUI fails to reflect it right.

- `2013-01-01` in Mysql displays as `2012-12-31`
- `2013-01-2` in Mysql displays as `2013-01-01`
- etc ... one day back

What I've tried:

1. Set java date types to  `java.time.Instant`
2. Set java date types to  `java.time.LocalDate`
3. Set java date types to  `java.sql.Date`
4. MySql date to `DATE`, `DATETIME`

I have tried different combinations, but none is working the way I wanted it. Where am I screwing up? 
Thank you.[image]

Comment: I'm guessing the time zone in the database and in your UI is different.

Comment: I thought I set the time zone correctly, but I was wrong. Thanks!